# take first value from never ending stream where values come in pairs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I built a formGroup with with different inputs. When an input changes, I would like to reactively react to it.

```
merge(
    this.formGroup.get('xy').valueChanges
    this.formGroup.valueChanges
).pipe("what comes here?").subscribe();
```

there is a special input field "xy" and when it changes, it has priority over  `this.formGroup.valueChanges` which it will trigger aswell. Therefore I only want to get the value from the first observable in any other case I will only get the values from the second observable which is fine. But how can I achieve this? `take(1)` will only work once and then never again which is not what I need. I probably tried every possible combination but I can't make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive values only from the Observable that emits a value first, I think you can use the `race` function instead of `merge` in this case.

From the docs: `race` subscribes to the observable that was the first to start emitting.
More details [here](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/race#race).

Comment: this won't work..as it's a never ending stream..it then only takes the value that arrived first and thats it. I believe I need to create my own operator..

Comment: Would ‘switch’ help instead of ‘merge’?

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `filter` can help you in this regard. The filter will stop emissions conditionally.

Try:

```
merge(
    this.formGroup.get('xy').valueChanges,
    this.formGroup.valueChanges.pipe(
       filter(formValueChanges => {
         // check formValueChanges and return true if `xy` was not the change
         // return true to allow emission from this, return false to not allow emission
       });
     ),
    ),
).subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question, "what comes here?" is...

```
   first(),
   delay(0),
   repeat()
```

Check this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nrzj5g. If you change the first name the input field validator is triggered. If you change the last name the formGroup validator is triggered. Check the console to see the result.

The relevant code in that example is in the `ngOnit` method

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const inputFieldValidator = this.form.get("firstName").valueChanges.pipe(
      tap(() => console.log("Validating Input field"))
    );
    const formGroupValidator = this.form.valueChanges.pipe(
      tap(() => console.log("Validating FormGroup"))
    );
    const validator = merge(inputFieldValidator, formGroupValidator).pipe(
      first(),
      delay(0),
      repeat()
    );
    validator.subscribe();
  }
```

Just to add a short explanation: `first()` is the same as `take(1)` as you suggested. But `first()` alone would end the stream so we need `repeat()` to start again but... then we also need the `delay(0)` because, for some reason, the repeat operator would let both observables get thru if we hadn't that delay in place. You can try commenting the delay operator.